# Why is this element showing up differently in internet explorer than in Chrome?

Tags: browser, styles

My cart progress bar looks perfect in chrome with the triangle at the end of it. On internet explorer it breaks. What's going wrong?

https://www.headsets.com/cart/addcart.html?split_shipping=cart_progress_bar_on

[image]